# How to get the definition of any CONSTRAINT using any system object?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, constraints

As we can get the definition of Stored Procedures, UDFs and Triggers using sp_helptext and sql_modules etc as these are system objects of MS SQL Server.
Similarly, I want any such system objects to get the definition of a CONSTRAINT almost similar as SSMS's UI from where we do "Script Constraint as" and then "Create to".

Comment: See [sys.sysconstraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190365) and the [follow-up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187997) about the views replacing this compatibility view. How to use these views depends on what exactly you want to do with the definition. If you need them scripted as text, using [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms162557) may be more convenient.

Comment: I want definition something like " ALTER TABLE myTable ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_added]  DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [added]" for constraint [DF_MyTable_added]